# Insert fails when looping through api request only excutes first query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, api

I am trying to retrieve a list of names from a table in sql server then use axios and node to make an API request 100 names or less at a time, then I am trying to insert the returned data into a new sql table.While i have been able to get it to work up to the API call the insert part hasn't worked yet for me. When i have done a limited number of inserts 4 or 5 it has only inserted the first query and when i have tried larger ones it has fail entirely.

SQL queries

```
const selectStatment = "SELECT [CandidateId] AS id, ( CASE LEN(REPLACE([CandidateName],' ','')) WHEN LEN([CandidateName]) - 1 then PARSENAME(REPLACE([CandidateName],' ','.'), 2) ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE([CandidateName],' ','.'), 3) END ) AS firstName, PARSENAME(REPLACE([CandidateName],' ','.'), 1) AS lastName ";
const cleanWherequery = 'WHERE NOT firstName IS NULL OR NOT firstName IS NULL ANd NOT lastName IS NULL';
const sqlTable = '##apiTable';
const tempQuery = `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##apiTable, ##clean; ${selectStatment} INTO ##clean FROM [dbo].[DimCandidate]; SELECT * INTO ${sqlTable} FROM ##clean ${cleanWherequery}`;
let insertValues = '';
const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO sql_GetGender (id, firstName, lastName, likelyGender, score, probabilityCalibrated) VALUES`;
```

API call and insert

```
const getGender = (data) => axios.post('/api2/json/genderBatch', data)
.then(function(data){
  return res = data.data;
})
.then(function(res){
  for(let index = 0; index < res.personalNames.length; index++){
    if((index + 1) == res.personalNames.length){
      insertValues += `(${res.personalNames[index]['id']}, '${res.personalNames[index]['firstName']}', '${res.personalNames[index]['lastName']}', '${res.personalNames[index]['likelyGender']}', ${res.personalNames[index]['score']}, ${res.personalNames[index]['probabilityCalibrated']});`;
       let pass = insertValues;
       return pass;
       insertValues = ' ';
    }else{
      insertValues += `(${res.personalNames[index]['id']}, '${res.personalNames[index]['firstName']}', '${res.personalNames[index]['lastName']}', '${res.personalNames[index]['likelyGender']}', ${res.personalNames[index]['score']}, ${res.personalNames[index]['probabilityCalibrated']}),`;
    }
  }
  console.log(insertValues);
}).then(function(res){
  new sql.Request().query(`${insertQuery} ${res}`, (err, result) => {
        console.dir(result)
    })
})
.catch(function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
```

Database call

```
(async function(){
  try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(dbConfig);
    let createTemp = await pool.request()
                               .query(`${tempQuery}`);

    let fetchQuery = await pool.request()
                                 .query(`SELECT TOP 3 id, firstName, lastName FROM ${sqlTable}`);

    let resData = await fetchQuery.recordset;

    let count = 0

    let elemlength = resData.length;

    resData.forEach(function(elem, i){
      printData.push(elem)
      count += 1;
      if(printData.length == 2){
        console.log(`${printData.length} Reached`);
        let personalNamesJson = {
          'personalNames' : printData
        }
        getGender(personalNamesJson);
        printData = [];
      }else if(printData.length < 2 && count == elemlength){
        console.log(`${printData.length} was left`);
        let personalNamesJson = {
          'personalNames' : printData
        }
        getGender(personalNamesJson);
      }
    })

  } catch (e) {

    console.log(e);
    sql.close()

  } finally {
    sql.close()
    console.log('connection closed')
  }
})()
```

I am expecting something like this with a different rowAffected number
{ recordsets: [],
  recordset: undefined,
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 4 ] }

What i am getting on the 2nd+ insert is 
undefined

Answer (score 0):

You put your insert values into the insertValues variable but then never use it.  Instead of ${res}, you need to use ${insertValues} in your third "then" clause.